# For a linear map $T:\mathbb{R}^5\to\mathbb{R}^3$, if $b\in\mathrm{range}(T)$, there are infinitely many $x\in\mathbb{R}^5$ such that $Tx=b$.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

For a linear map $T:\mathbb{R}^5\to\mathbb{R}^3$, if $b\in\mathrm{range}(T)$, there are infinitely many $x\in\mathbb{R}^5$ such that $Tx=b$.

Proof) $T$ has $3\times 5$ standard matrix $A$ and since $b\in\mathrm{range}(T)$, $Ay=b$ has a solution. So the reduced row echelon form of $[A:b]$ cannot have the third row of the form $[0\cdots 0\,k]$ with $k\neq0$ and since $A$ is $3\times 5$, we need free variables to express solutions of $Ay=b$. So there are infinitely many $y$ such that $Ay=b$.

I was wondering if the above way is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is good, although I think there is a slight lack of detail in "we need free variables to express solutions of $Ay = b$". Here is an approach that doesn't use any matrices.

The rank-nullity theorem tells us that
$$\dim \text{Range($T$)} + \dim\text{Ker}(T) = 5$$
Since Range$(T) \subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$, we have $\dim\text{Range}(T) \leq 3$
and so the equality above implies
$\dim\text{Ker}(T) \geq 2$. We know that 2-dimensional subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^5$ are infinite, so we can choose infinitely many $x \in \mathbb{R}^5$ with $Tx = 0$.

Finally, since $Ty = b$ for some $y \in \mathbb{R}^5$, we can obtain an infinite family of solutions by noticing that
$$T(y+x) = Ty + Tx = Ty +0= b $$
for all $x \in \text{Ker}(T)$.